# Cascading drop down list won't load from database (MVC, JSON, C#)

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

All -

I am new to MVC/Javascript and have tried multiple tutorials on ways to get a cascading drop down list working for State and City on an MVC view. My most recent attempt I am using this [Example](https://abctutorial.com/Post/26/how-to-create-cascading-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc-%7C-using-jquery-ajax)

The states populate from the DB, but the cities are a blank drop down with a bout 10 empty spaces. Regardless of what state I pick.  What am I missing? Thanks for looking and advice/feedback!

Here is the DB Tables info:

Regions (contains states): Id (PK Int), Name (Varchar(255) state/regionname), CountryId (Int) 
Cities (Contains cities): Id (PK Int), Name (Varchar(255) state/name), RegionID (int, linkes to region table)

Here is the view model:

```
public class UserAds
{
    public int addId { get; set; }
    public int userCreatedAcctId { get; set; }
    public string userForAccEmail { get; set; }
    public string photoFileLocation { get; set; }
    public string addTitle { get; set; }
    public string addDesc { get; set; }
    public string addPersonalityTraits { get; set; }
    public string addHobbies { get; set;}
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State / Region")]
    public int stateId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int cityId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateAd()
    {
        List<Region> stateList = db.Regions.ToList();
        ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(stateList, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetCitiesList(int StateId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<City> CityList = db.Cities.Where(x => x.RegionId == StateId).ToList();
        return Json(CityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The view:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    @if (ViewBag.StateList != null)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.stateId, ViewBag.StateList as SelectList, "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    }
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select City--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stateId").change(function () {
        $.get("GetCitiesList", { StateId: $("#stateId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#cityId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#cityId").append("<option value=" + row.Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
```

[Javascript debugger in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JqHL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the below line, you are missing a single quote after `value=`

```
$("#cityId").append("<option value=" + row.Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
```

It should ideally be something like below-

```
$("#cityId").append("<option value='" + row.Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that I still get a Javascript error in the debugger "Line: 502
Error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected"

Comment: Do u see `data` object having any values within the ajax? If yes, that what is the structure of the object?

Comment: Sorry, still learning, but when I add data to the watch list in the IE Debugger I get Data <not available>. Is this what you mean or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: I am not sure if that would be the right way to do it. Maybe, within the `function(data) { }`, you should try adding a `console.log(data)` (to print in `console` section of the developer tools) or `alert(data)` (to display within a pop up window)  as the first line and see what is in `data`

Comment: I tried adding console.log below.... I don't see console output but I see an error data is undefined. 

'<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#stateId").change(function () {
            $.get("GetCitiesList", { StateId: $("#stateId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#cityId").empty();
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#cityId").append("<option value='" + row.Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>'

Comment: `data` is undefined means the response from your `GetCitiesList` api is null...checking why that is null might help.